# Run PowerShell command (with pipeline) in CMD

Tags: powershell, command-prompt

When we run the following command in PowerShell:

```
get-date | sc C:\temp\date.log
```

it creates date.log file with current date.

But if we run the same via CMD:

```
powershell get-date | sc C:\temp\date.log
```

It complains:

> ERROR:  Unrecognized command
>
> ```
> DESCRIPTION:
>         SC is a command line program used for communicating with the
>         Service Control Manager and services.
> USAGE:
>         sc <server> [command] [service name] <option1> <option2>...
> ```

Apparently, CMD confuses pipeline meant for POSH, with its own.

Can anyone point me how to make it run via CMD?

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
powershell -Command " & {Get-Date | sc c:\tmp\date.log}"
```

[CMD and PowerShell](https://web.archive.org/web/20140206160933/http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx)

Comment: Broken link here.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20140206160933/http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As long as the pipe symbol is escaped from cmd with double-quotes, it will work.  Sc is an unfortunate alias, since there's an sc.exe command in windows.  ? or where-object might be easier than trying to embed an extra set of double-quotes in a query.

```
powershell "get-date | set-content c:\tmp\date.log"

powershell "get-ciminstance win32_volume | ? label -like 'month *' | select label"
```