# format list is not recognised in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, command

I executed a command and in that i used "fl" format list. Output is "fl" is not recognised as internal or external command. I faced same issue with "Get-WmiObject " also. Feel free to comment for any other info.

```
C:\Windows\system32>powershell.exe -Command Get-WmiObject -query "select * from msiscsi_nicconfig where Instancename LIKE '%ROOT\\ISCSIPRT\\0000_0%'" -namespace "root/wmi" | fl MacAddress
```

Output:

```
'fl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 1):

The pipe and fl are being interpreted by DOS, not Powershell, and since fl is not a DOS command you are getting the error.  You need to do something like this:

`powershell.exe -Command " & {Get-WmiObject -query "select * from msiscsi_nicconfig where Instancename LIKE '%ROOT\\ISCSIPRT\\0000_0%'" -namespace "root/wmi" | fl MacAddress}"`

See [Run PowerShell command (with pipeline) in CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801976/run-powershell-command-with-pipeline-in-cmd)

Comment: When i execute the above command i am getting output as "access denied" @Tony

Comment: Did you search for "get-wmiobject access denied"?  That's what I would do.  That is a completely separate problem.

Comment: I just executed the command what you specified and the output is "access denied"

Comment: Yes.  The problem that was occurring when you posted the question was being returned by DOS because it didn't know what "fl" was.  Now that the powershell command is properly formatted, the Get-WmiObject command is returning an "access denied" error.  Accordingly, I advised you to search (the Internet) for "get-wmiobject access denied", which is the best advice anyone will give you.  There are already 100s of pages devoted to this particular error, and it doesn't make sense for someone to try to fix that problem in some comments here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to run powershell from `cmd` command line. Your powershell command ends with `"root/wmi"`. The pipeline `| fl MacAddress` is interpreted by `cmd` not by Powershell.

You should run the entire command inside Powershell.